# Simple Accordion not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, accordion

I have this simple accordion that I got from CSS tricks (and manipulated a tiny bit), it works great everywhere except IE7 (in IE9, using dev tools to show IE7 mode), however when I tested the unmanipulated version from CSS tricks it works fine in IE7.

Here is the jsfiddle from CCS Tricks: http://jsfiddle.net/drpKm/

Here is what I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/y6m2N/3/

Any ideas on how to get it to work in IE? I've tried everything I can think of. The only change I made form the CSS tricks version was putting the anchor tag outside of the dt tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this pretty much fixed things... http://jsfiddle.net/y6m2N/21/

IE didn't like the anchor tag being around the dt tag, it worked everywhere else fine, but as always, IE7 was the exception. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I've got it working for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y6m2N/3/)

A couple of notes.

1. You didn't need the `noConflict()` method since you are already passing jQuery as a parameter.
2. I  added the # to the href as Safari won't work properly without something in the attribute.
3. The fiddle you linked didn't have jQuery loaded.

Comment: 1. good to know
2. thanks
3. I had realized that and changed it but forgot to update it

It's still not working in IE7 for me though. Did you test it in IE7?

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. SO did not inform me there was a comment. I shall endeavour to check tomorrow as it is very late here just now.